# Give a subharmonic function that is not real analytic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, potential-theory

Is there a  function $f(x)$ defined on an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ ($ k\geq2 $) such that

1) $f$ is $C^{2}$ smooth,

2) $f$ is subharmonic, i.e. the laplacian  $\Delta f$ of $f$ is positive,

3) $f$ is not real analytic?

Answer (score 1):

Define $f(x,y)= |x|^3 + x^2.$ Then $f$ is $C^2$ and $\Delta f(x,y) = 6|x|+2.$ If $f$ were real analytic, then its Laplacian would be real analytic. But clearly this fails.

Answer (score 1):

In the whole plane, take the standard (smooth, radial, positive, supported on $B_1(0)$) mollifier $\rho$ and the fundamental solution of the Laplace operator $\Gamma$, s.t. $\Delta\Gamma=-\delta$, where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta (you can do this in all dimensions). The convolution $u=-\rho *\Gamma$ is smooth and subharmonic: $-\Delta (\rho *\Gamma)= -(\Delta \Gamma)*\rho=\delta*\rho\geq 0$. It is not analytic because $\rho *\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x)$ outside the unitary ball, as $\Gamma$ is harmonic away from $0$ (standard regularization preserves harmonic functions) and thanks to unique analytic continuation.

You can do it more generally taking $u=-\Gamma*\phi$ for, say, a positive test function $\phi$